# Add taxonomy titles drupal

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I want to create a taxonomy three like this:

```
A:
  Abert
  Alfred
B:
  Bert
  Bernard
C:
  Chris
...
```

So everything that starts with an A goes into the a category automatically.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree(MY_VID);
$items = array();
foreach($tree AS $term){
  $letter = mb_substr($term->name, 0, 1);
  $items[$letter]['data'] = $letter;
  $items[$letter]['children'][] = l($term->name, taxonomy_term_path($term));
}
ksort($items);
print theme_item_list($items);
?>
```

Comment: custom module, template file, anywhere you want